# Why do I have to keep making my " no" capital to make my program work in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Here's the code I seek to understand. It receives user input, and my concern is that it only works when I type "No", not "no".

```
houseprice = int(input("please enter the house cost: $"))

while houseprice <= 0:
    print("please enter a valid number try again")
    houseprice = int(input("please enter the house cost: $"))  

familyincome = int(input("please enter your family income: $"))
houseowened = input("have you owened a house before? ('Yes' or 'No')")
while not houseowened == 'Yes' and houseowened == 'No':
    print("please enter a valid answer")
    houseowened = input("have you owened a house before? ('Yes' or 'No')")    

if houseprice > 500000 or familyincome > 100000 or houseowened == 'Yes':
    print("eligeble")
else:
    if houseowened == 'No' or familyincome < 100000 or houseprice < 500000 :
        print("not eligible")
```

Comment: Was your question answered in a satisfactory way? If so, please mark the correct answer using the checkmark beside it. This helps the community to know that the question was answered.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please mark the correct answer with the checkbox beside it. Otherwise, what can we do to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the comparisons in your code. They're comparing against the string `"No"`. If you want it to accept the lowercase form, perhaps you should do something like this everywhere you have `houseowned == 'No'`:

```
(houseowened.lower() == 'no')
```

This variation will accept any capitalization. Be sure to make the corresponding change for all `yes`es.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing strings in pretty much all languages, it is a literal comparison.

So the following code:

```
if(MyString == "No")
```

Will only pass if the string is `"No"` and exactly that. `"no"`, `"No  "`, `"  no"` and other such examples will all not pass the check as they are different.

Most languages offer several tools that can make your life a lot easier on this.

For Python this is called `lower()`, which will convert all uppercase letters of a string to lowercase.

So `"Foo".lower();` will give you `"foo"`

Second is `strip()`. This one removes leading and trailing 'whitespace' characters off the ends of the string, so `" Foo   "` will become "Foo"

Using both combined makes checking string values a lot simpler.